# Is there a way to Parameterize a baseUrl in Cypress?

Tags: node.js, automation, cypress

I have an app where we set a baseUrl in cypress i.e. "http://localhost:3000/" but I would like to parameterize the port number. Is there a way to do this in Cypress? I see that there is a `--port={x}`flag for cypress. Can I access that?

Answer (score 1):

By itself, setting `--port` in the command line **does nothing to your baseUrl**.

It's not the same port as in `http://localhost:4000`, instead it is used by the Cypress runner.

Change it only if you know what you are doing!

Instead, use a custom property

```js
yarn cypress open --env buport=8000
```

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      if (config.env.buport) {
        config.baseUrl = config.baseUrl.replace('4000', config.env.buport)
      }
      return config
    },
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'    // defaults to port 4000
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override your port number by using the `--port` flag. Something like this:

```js
npx cypress run --port 8080
```

Also, you can override the entire base URL through CLI, like this:

```js
CYPRESS_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000/ cypress run
```